# Writing to .fini_array

Tags: linux, c, binary-code, format-string, virtual-memory

I'm learning about format string exploits, and am attempting to use one on an example program to overwrite the `.fini_array` section in virtual memory with a stack address containing shellcode (and hence redirect execution to the shellcode once `main` exits). Unfortunately, trying to write to this address raises a segmentation fault, and I have written the following program to try to understand what's going on. (Disclaimer, I am running x64 linux with ASLR disabled while I am learning.)

```
//fini_test.c
#include <stdio.h>
#define OFFSET 0x555555554000

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    unsigned long int addr;
    char **ptr;
    static int canary=0xdeadbeef;

    if(argc<2) {
        printf("Usage: %s <position to write to in object file>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(0); }

    addr=stroul(argv[1], ptr, 16)+OFFSET;

    printf("[*] about to print\n");
    printf("writing to %p\n%n", (void *) addr, (int *) addr);
    printf("[*] print complete\n");
    printf("canary @ %p\t%d\t0x%08x\n\n", &canary, canary, canary);
    exit(0);
}
```

So, the program simply takes a position in the object file as a command line argument, and then writes some bytes to the corresponding position in the virtual memory space of the process. With GDB I found that the right offset between the location in the object file and the location in the virtual memory space was `0x555555554000`.

I then compiled and used `objdump` to find the desired sections in the object file.

```
$gcc fini_test.c -o fini_test
$objdump -h ./fini_test
Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA               LMA               File off  Algn
...
 19 .fini_array   00000008  0000000000200da8  0000000000200da8  00000da8  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
...
 22 .data         00000014  0000000000201000  0000000000201000  00001000  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
...
```

So, the position of the `.data` section in `./fini_test` is `0x201000` and the position of the `.fini_array` section is `0x200da8`. I also noted that, like the `.data` section, the `.fini_array` section does *not* have a `READONLY` flag, so I assumed that I should be able to write to it with the appropriate command line argument. However, this is how execution behaved:

```
$./dtors_test 0x2010000
[*] about to print
writing to 0x555555755000
[*] print complete
canary @ 0x555555755010 -559038737  0xdeadbeef

$./dtors_test 0x201010
[*] about to print
writing to 0x555555755010
[*] print complete
canary @ 0x555555755010 26  0x0000001a

$./dtors_test 0x200da8
[*] about to print
writing to 0x555555754da8
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

First, to verify that my code and choice of `OFFSET` were right, I tried to overwrite the value of `canary`. As a first approximation I just inputted the position of the `.data` section, which was unsuccessful because – as inspecting the outputted address of `canary` shows – the value of `canary` is stored beneath the two pointers `addr` and `ptr`. Hence I inputted the position of the `.data` section plus `0x10` to account for this, and indeed successfully overwrote the value of `canary` with the expected value of `26` (precisely the number of bytes in the string `"writing to 0x555555755010\n"`.)

So everything to that point is working as expected. However, I then try to write to the start of the `.fini_array` section* and a segmentation fault is raised. This surprises me because this section is not marked as `READONLY` in the object file; can anyone help me understand what's going on? Thank you in advance

---

*I know that destructor addresses are not stored at exactly the start of the `.fini_array` section, and so even if I could write to that address it would not yield the desired results. But for now, before I cross that bridge, I'm just trying to understand why I can't write to an address that seemingly does not have a `READONLY` flag enabled. As a broader question, general references to understanding how `.fini_array` works in ELF files would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Judging by the addresses... Is your binary compiled with PIE? That might make it difficult.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `-Wl,-z,norelro` to disable RELRO.